# Using Flask and SQLite, how do I migrate from one database schema to a new one?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a simple web application using sqlite as my database with the help of flask-sqlalchemy. After creating the application, I realise I need to add a new column to the database. However, when I modify the models.py file directly, they say the new column is not available as the error.

My understanding is this is probably because the database has already been created so I am unable to edit the models.py directly. May I know what I can do to add the 'photo' column in the database? Should I delete the current data base file (db.sqlite) and create the tables again?

Here's the models.py file currently:

```
  1 from flask_login import UserMixin
  2 from . import db
  3
  4 class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
  5     __tablename__ = "user"
  6     __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
  7
  8     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  9     email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
 10     password = db.Column(db.String(100))
 11     name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
 12
 13 class Item(UserMixin, db.Model):
 14     __tablename__ = "item"
 15     __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
 16
 17     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 18     item = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
 19     description = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
 20     occurdate = db.Column(db.Date)
 21     time = db.Column(db.Time)
 22     # photo = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
```

Comment: Read through this page: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a SQL database and you want to make changes to the schema of an existing database, you basically have three options:

1. Use a database migration tool (best for large projects)
2. Do it manually yourself (perhaps better for small projects)
3. Drop the database and start from scratch

### Migration Tools

These are tools that migrate the database for you, usually by versioning each iteration of the database and using scripts that migrate the database between versions. [Alembic](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic) is the officially supported tool for SQLAlchemy and generally recommended by a lot of users.

### Do it yourself

If you don't want the hassle of using a tool, you can connect directly to your database (for example by using the sqlite command line tool) and running `alter table` commands. This is what a migration tool automates for you, but if you want to keep it simple and interact directly with your database, using `alter table` commands is usually pretty simple.

### Drop and recreate

You can also of course just delete your database and start from scratch.

Often, when you're just prototyping a project and you haven't made a lot of progress yet on deciding on how you want your tables laid out, this is the best approach.

Once you have real data in a production database, however, this isn't an option so it's probably worthwhile to familiarize yourself with the first two methods either way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will read through the website you shared as well!